# Switch background image on hover using vanilla Javascript and data attributes

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover, background-image

I'm wanting to be able to switch the background image of a `<div>` when hovering over a link. The `<div>` would not have a background image on the first page load.

Here's what I currently have:

```
<div class="background">
  <a href="#" data-bkgimg="link-1-bkg.jpg">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-bkgimg="link-2-bkg.jpg">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

And here's what I'm trying to achieve on hover:

```
<div class="background" style="background-image: url('link-1-bkg.jpg');">
  <a href="#" data-bkgimg="link-1-bkg.jpg" class="is-active">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-bkgimg="link-2-bkg.jpg">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

I appreciate something like this can be achieved using jQuery, but I'm looking for a vanilla JS solution if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Check this codepen](https://codepen.io/TheLast/pen/EXzeMQ)

```
var link1 = document.getElementById("link1");
var div1 = document.getElementById("div1");

link1.addEventListener("mouseover", function( event ) { 
    var bg = event.target.dataset.bkgimg;
    div1.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+bg+')';
});

link1.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) { 
    div1.style.backgroundImage = '';
});
```

That's only example (but still working) code to help you get the idea.
Also, if you're familiar with JQuery but want to use vanilla.js, consider this page: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

**Update:**
As you might noticed there are different ways of doing that, however the main idea is to store the data attribute with background-image link, `data-bkgimg="link-2-bkg.jpg"` and set it to div's background using js mouse events, like `mouseover`

Comment: This looks like the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this in vanilla js what you can do is simply get the element and attach an event listener to the mouse event, like this:

```
var el = document.querySelector("#hoverItem");

el.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
    el.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-640-480-10.jpg')";
});

el.addEventListener("mouseout", function(){
    el.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://lorempixel.com/output/abstract-q-c-640-480-3.jpg')";
});
```

Working example:

https://jsbin.com/ceqiku/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Add `addEventListener` to anchor tags directly  or add class to anchor tag then add `addEventListener` to it, and get `data-bkgimg` through `getAttribute` and then set or remove `background-image`

```js
var el = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

function setImage() {
  var bg = this.getAttribute('data-bkgimg');
  this.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + bg + ")";
}

function removeImage() {
  this.style.backgroundImage = "url('')";
}

for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
  el[i].addEventListener('mouseover', setImage, false);
  el[i].addEventListener('mouseout', removeImage, false);
}
```

```css
a {
  padding: 30px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="background" style="background-image: url('link-1-bkg.jpg');">
  <a href="#" data-bkgimg="https://rlv.zcache.com/crash_test_dummy_marker_classic_round_sticker-r8b36e2d5c0f74a4c843565523094b867_v9wth_8byvr_324.jpg" class="is-active">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#" data-bkgimg="https://dummyimage.com/300.png/09f/fff">Link 2</a>
</div>
```